# Capturing AES encrypted strings (including slashes) with Django URLs?

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have an encrypted string, `nITUk+N1ly2cjO1jLJ9/vdsEsLD7AqpMWF4iEfad3AO8yeiAYPqB4tBehaBGT0q+`

how do I pass the value to a variable?

my url configuration is

```
url(r'^secure/(?P<code>[a-zA-Z0-9/\+]\w+)$', 'user.views.decrypt_url'),
```

Thanks

[regexr](http://regexr.com/3bfkj)

Comment: First encode the encrypted string in something that's URL safe, e.g. `urllib.quote` or `.encode('Base64').replace('\n','')` then decode in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to `.*` and it works.

```
url(r'^secure/(?P<code>(.*))$', 'user.views.decrypt_url'),
```

[regexr](http://regexr.com/3bfle)